# Existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I have an **unity3D game** and a **winforms** c# application and **Microsoft SQLServer 2014** installed on a **Windows 10 enterprise**.

The winforms c# application is a tool for user to insert data into database and the unity3D game will read data from the same database and they are working perfectly with the same connection string for both winforms c# application and unity3D game.

**Problem is:** When I deploy all of them to my client's computer which running windows 10 pro the windows form application working but I faced this error when running the unity3D game "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", and this is my connection string for both winform application and unity 3D game:

`"server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS2014;database=diembao;User Id=sa;Password=111111;"`

So anyone please tell me why I'm facing this error and how to fix? I've try to replace "localhost" with my computer name and my computer local IP address but this error still occur.

**Update:**
*One more information, **When I change from SQLEXPRESS to SQLServer** for developer edition I got this error instead: "SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used"*

Comment: Is Windows Firewall running on this system and if so, is it blocking one or more of your applications?  You may check the event logs for more information.

Comment: Windows Firewall is turned off, and all local ports on my computer are allowed to be opened anytime,and why down vote my question for no reason?

Comment: for one more information, When I change from SQLEXPRESS to SQLServer for developer edition I got this error instead: "SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used"

Comment: Can you share your connection string with code in unity?

Comment: private static DatabaseController db;
    SqlConnection con;
    public DatabaseController()
    {
        string connectionString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Config.txt");

        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

Comment: I did not down vote your question, but apparently someone else did. It looks like it has been returned to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who is facing the same problem as mine, I resolved this by changing connection string from

> server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS2014;database=diembao;User
>   Id=sa;Password=111111;

to

> server=**tcp:127.0.0.1**\SQLEXPRESS2014;database=diembao;User
>   Id=sa;Password=111111;